# Zeros of Complex Polynomial and Fundamental Theorem of Algebra

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $p(z)=$ polynomial over $\mathbb{C}$. I want to show (possibly, without Fundamental Theorem of Algebra)

> There exists a disc $D$ in $\mathbb{C}$ such that the (possible) zeros of $p(z)$ lie inside the disc.

My question is whether we **need** Fundamental Theorem of algebra for this?

---

I tried to proceed in the following way.

(1) The polynomial $p(z)$ has at most $deg(p)$ zeros.

(2) We can certainly find then a disc which contains all possible zeros.

It is the statement (1) where I want to clarify whether I am using fundamental theorem of algebra.

Answer (score 1):

The Fundamental Theorem of Algebra asserts that there *are* $\deg p$ zeroes (if you count multiplicity).  If all you want to know is that there are *at most* $\deg p$ zeroes, you don't need the FTA; just use the fact that complex polynomials have a unique factorization into irreducibles.